# TermStore Count is 0

Tags: sharepoint, taxonomy

**Overview**
I am observing a really strange behaviour with code which attempts to retrieve the TermStore from the TaxonomySession. The code looks like this:

```
            using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite(url))
            {
            TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(mySite);

            // Get all the TermStores associated with the provided site.
            TermStoreCollection stores = session.TermStores;
            Console.WriteLine(stores.Count);
```

Here is the issue:

1. The above code does not return any TermStores, i.e. the count is zero
2. If I run the following PowerShell script from the same command prompt, I get 1 TermStore in the count.

   ```
   $site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("https://mysite") 
   $session = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site) 
   $session.TermStores.Count
   ```

I have tried the following:

1. My Managed Metadata Application Proxy is a part of the default proxy group
2. The administrator for the Managed Metadata Service is configured correctly
3. The permissions for the Managed Metadata Service are configured correctly
4. The Managed Metadata application pool is running under the farm account
5. Modifying the code above to run under elevated privileges

The weird thing is that the first block of code above DOES NOT retrieve any TermStore(s) when compiled as an executable and invoked from a command window, which is running under the farm credentials. IN THE SAME window, I can copy and paste the second block of the equivalent PowerShell scripts and have it run!

Also, this issue is only happening on our Production environment. The same executable ran successfully on our DEV, TEST and Pre Prod environments.

Any help at this stage will be much appreciated.

Comment: We've run in to similar issues when calling termstore from powershell. We haven't figured out why, but programmatically making a http-request to the admin termstore-page seems to wake it up and then we can get data from it.

Comment: This just got stranger today.
 
We ported the EXE code to PowerShell and it ran successfully today.
 
We still do not know why the EXE was failing. Once we are done with our release, we may come back and do some further diagnosis and I will update the thread later.

Comment: Just a thought, can it be that you didn't run the exe as 64-bit application?

Answer (score 1):

We encountered exactly the same issue in our test environment. But, our development servers are working as expected. My colleague was able to narrow down the issue and resolve it by updating hotfix available in Microsoft support.

The following are the details of the hotfix and information he could come across while researching on that particular issue.

- [Support download link](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB976462)

*For additional information:*

1. http://chrisforbesblogs.net/2009/12/02/the-managed-metadata-service-or-connection-is-currently-not-available
2. http://expectedexception.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/the-managed-metadata-service-or-connection-is-currently-not-available-the-application-pool-or-managed-metadata-web-service-may-not-have-been-started-please-contact-your-administrator/

Please consult your system administrator before updating any hotfix to servers. Hope this help you to fix the issue in your production environment.